# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver - heroku

Tags: java, mysql, heroku

Trying to create a database connection I use this code :

```
    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    basicDataSource.setUrl("mysql://b48516fc807a21:66a715a2@us-cdbr-east-04.cleardb.com/heroku_fca06dcb390cb0f?reconnect=true");
    basicDataSource.setUsername("b48516fc807a21");
    basicDataSource.setPassword("66a715a2");
```

But when I run my heroku app I receive this error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:289)
```

I've added mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin to my classpath and this does not seem to fix it. How to fix this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the JDBC URL for MySQL is [found here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

```
jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database] »
[?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...
```

You need to change yours accordingly. Pretty much just changing

```
mysql://...
```

to

```
jdbc:mysql://
```

This URL prefix scheme is how the JDBC Driver gets mapped and retrieved.